# Animated border menu mobile scrolling issue

Tags: mobile, navigation, touch, overflow, animated

I'm trying to build a web page in Rails using animated boder menu from tympanus.net - http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/AnimatedBorderMenus/index2.html aand it worked awesomely.. until I checked it on mobile devices.. Page is hosted here http://bios.herokuapp.com/

For some reason, it forces overflow: hidden; on body tag, and is also not giving any height value to the body. Result was that the page was unable to scroll on touch, and navigation would not lead anywhere, first screen would stay fixed. Placing height: auto; and overflow: auto; on body tag made navigating possible, but page is still not reacting to touch and is unable to scroll in such way.

Anybody has any idea what would cause this? Navigation is fixed (my first suspect), and div tags in content are having height: 100vh;. If fixed navigation with it's overlay div is the problem, how to go about it?

I would gladly share any code, but not sure which one would be helpful :)

Thank you for any info in advance.